How to turn a function into a parser in haskell (Megaparsec)
This is my current code for multiplying the first and last numbers in a string
type Parser = Parsec Void String
parsefirst :: Parser Int 
parsefirst = do 
    getnotdigits 
    x <- some digitChar
    y <- some finishstr 
    let z = ranParserRight y
    return $ read x * getrightnum x z
parseright :: Parser Int 
parseright = do 
    getnotdigits 
    x <- some digitChar
    y <- finishstr 
    let z = ranParserRight y
    return $ getrightnum x z
ranParserRight = parseMaybe parseright
getrightnum = fromMaybe . read 
finishstr = many (satisfy (const True))
getnotdigits = many (satisfy (not . isDigit))

I want to do something like this:
type Parser = Parsec Void String
parsefirst :: Parser Int 
parsefirst = do 
    getnotdigits 
    x <- some digitChar
    z <- simpleParserRight
    return $ read x * getrightnum x z
parseright :: Parser Int 
parseright = do 
    getnotdigits 
    x <- some digitChar
    z <- simpleParserRight 
    return $ getrightnum x z
simpleParserRight = toParser (parseMaybe parseright)
getrightnum = fromMaybe . read 
getnotdigits = many (satisfy (not . isDigit))

However, I don't think I can. I searched up the possible type signature in hoogle and came up empty.

Even if there is a better way to create a function in this situation, I have wanted to be able to turn functions into parsers many other times.

I understand that I could condence y <- some finishstr let z = ranParserRight y, by making a function to do that, but I would prefer a toParser function.

This is a bit of a weird request, in that usually parsers are composed, not chained. I'm unsure if you've completely missed the normal use pattern, or have used a far-oversimplified example to illustrate what you want.

Can you explain what you're trying to do in English? It's hard to tell from your code.

finishstr = many (satisfy (const True)) will fetch everyting after the some  digitChars, so this looks quite strange.

As stated, I wanted to multiply the first and last "numbers" in a string. I haven't done much parsing so there might be something I am missing, but essentially, I made a parseright function that gets rid of everything until it finds a number, gets the number, and tries to find if there is a number to the left, using parseMaybe. I haven't done much parsing and only use basic functions, so there might be an operator that would let me do this more efficiently. I know that I can use alternatives, but I never really understood how to nest parsers.

@willeM_VanOnsem That was the point, I wanted to run it on the parseMaybe function.

@user28080356: but parseMaybe essentially just tries to parse something and returns Just x if it parses to x, and Nothing otherwise, so that means the parser "wrapped" in the parseMaybe should just do the parsing according to the syntax rules of the item it aims to parse, and fail "" if that does not work.

I am new to parsing so there might be something simple that I don't understand

You should define a parseFirstInt parser and a parseLastInt parser, then construct a parser from them to parse (and maybe multiply) the two integers.

Are there any examples of good parsers in haskell I'm trying to learn how to use them. I don't really understand.

The way parseright works is it says
Get the first number,
see if there is another number accessible, if so, use that instead. I used parseMaybe and fromMaybe to achieve that.

The usual way to approach this sort of thing is to compose parsers together using the Applicative and Monad interfaces they provide.
{- cabal:
build-depends: base, megaparsec, parser-combinators
-}

import Data.Char

import Text.Megaparsec
import Data.Void

import Control.Monad.Combinators (skipManyTill)


type Parser = Parsec Void String

ignoreUntil :: Parser a -> Parser a
ignoreUntil = skipManyTill anySingle

ignoreRemaining :: Parser ()
ignoreRemaining = ignoreUntil eof


num :: Parser Int
num = read <$> some (satisfy isDigit)

firstNum :: Parser Int
firstNum = ignoreUntil num

lastNum :: Parser Int
lastNum = last <$> some (try (ignoreUntil num))


multiplyFirstAndLast :: Parser Int
multiplyFirstAndLast = (*) <$> firstNum <*> lastNum <* ignoreRemaining

This is an example that can be loaded with cabal repl to experiment with. I've pulled in the parser-combinators library so I can import the additional tools that megaparsec doesn't re-export. Note that megaparsec does depend on and re-export many functions from parser-combinators, so I'm not adding a new compile-time dependency. I just wanted skipManyTill without having to reimplement it myself.
So if I load it and experiment with it a bit:
$ cabal repl parse.hs
Ok, one module loaded.
ghci> parseMaybe multiplyFirstAndLast "blue, 2, 1, 5, fish"
Just 10
ghci> parseMaybe multiplyFirstAndLast "3blue, 2, 1, 5, fish7"
Just 21
ghci> parseMaybe multiplyFirstAndLast "The number is: 4"
Nothing
ghci> parseMaybe multiplyFirstAndLast "The numbers are: 4 and 3"
Just 12
ghci> parseMaybe multiplyFirstAndLast "The numbers are: 4, 25, and 3"
Just 12

That looks like it achieves your stated goal, if not by doing it exactly how you thought you would.
Some implementation notes:

Parser combinators are intended to be a composable interface. They should be built from composable units which are then connected via the the composition interfaces like Applicative or Monad. (I used only Applicative directly, but Monad is available for operations that are more complex or are context-sensitive.)
I started with a couple generic utilities. ignoreUntil throws away input until it finds something that matches the provided parser. ignoreRemaining throws away input until the end.
num and firstNum are not especially interesting applications of existing utilities.
lastNum separates finding the last occurrence of something from finding all occurrences. It's easy to use the provided some combinator to make a list of things that match. As a separate step, last is applied to the list it made. Separating these concerns reduces the amount I need to think about in a way I enjoy.
On the other hand, lastNum also needs to use try, megaparsec's biggest API failure. For performance reasons, megaparsec throws away partial input that matches the start of a parser. But if the parser ends up failing later, that input is gone and megaparsec is in a state where it can't try alternate parses of the same data, so all parses fail. The try combinator exists to mark a point where it should start saving input, so that if it decides to try an alternative parser the input is still there to observe. (This is not the same as general backtracking. There is no way to make megaparsec do general backtracking. Between that fact and the necessity of using try, I often recommend against using parsec-like libraries. Unless you need performance at the cost of a good API, I recommend going elsewhere.)


This is my second parser, I am not very good at understanding how it is supposed to work and how to use most functions so I might take a while to understand all this. However, it is much better and will let me experiment more. Do you know any ways to learn more about megaparsec. All examples I found were either very simple or extremely complex.

what is the point of the <* ignore remaining?

@user28080356 parseMaybe fails if the parser doesn't match the entire input. <* combines two parsers so that both consume their inputs but the result of the second parser is ignored. So adding <* ignoreRemaining allows the parser to succeed when there are non-digit characters at the end of the input.
